Rust methods generic and specific
I think I'm trying to do a perfectly normal thing here, which is to have a generic type with a default method implementation, and a specific type with a more specific one. The code seems pretty straightforward:
struct V<L> { value: L, }

impl<L> V<L> {
    fn m(&self) { println!("generic"); }
}
struct MyClass;

impl V<MyClass> {
    fn m(&self) { println!("specific"); }
}

pub fn main() {
    let v1 = V { value: MyClass };
    v1.m();
}

This is giving me a duplicate method error--the same error one would get defining the same method name in two impl blocks. But isn't Rust supposed to be able to find the specific one over the generic one?
error[E0592]: duplicate definitions with name `m`
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     fn m(&self) { println!("generic"); }
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ duplicate definitions for `m`
...
8 |     fn m(&self) { println!("specific"); }
  |     ----------- other definition for `m`

error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
  --> src/main.rs:12:8
   |
12 |     v1.m();
   |        ^ multiple `m` found
   |
note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl for the type `V<L>`
  --> src/main.rs:3:5
   |
3  |     fn m(&self) { println!("generic"); }
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl for the type `V<MyClass>`
  --> src/main.rs:8:5
   |
8  |     fn m(&self) { println!("specific"); }
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^


Sadly no. Rust currently does not have specialization. You can have separate implementations for different concrete types, but once one of them is generic, you cannot specialize others.

There are some unsable features and some autoref tricks you can use, but they are very limited in what you can do with them.

The easy thing would be to make the specifics implement all functions, and provide default implementations as plain old functions. A lot of duplicated code that way.

Another way is to put the default implementations in a trait, and provide the specific implementations when implementing the trait for the specific type. But this means that the default implementations can't access struct fields easily, and that you need to impl Trait for Specific {} even if you want to keep all the default implementations.

If I understand correctly you want specialisation here. It is currently in development and the issues are being tracked here. Here you are trying to override a generic implementaion and not default implementation which are for concrete types. Default implementation can be overriden but generic cannot be.

Thanks. Because I'm sure I'm not the only one looking for this feature who didn't happen to know the magic word "specialization", and who doesn't spend his days on the Rust issues list, I'm leaving the question up despite the stupid downvotes.
